# PUB-SUB ZeroMQ не принимаются/отправляются пакеты

Tags: python, zeromq

изучаю python, в частности - взаимодействие с сокетами, и, разбираясь с взаимодействием между разными типами сокетов в библиотеке ZeroMQ, столкнулся с тем, что при использовании связи сокетов PUB-SUB клиент не получает данных (методом пихания в каждую строчку кода принта выяснилось, что код клиента стопорится в цикле, пытаясь принять пакеты). В чем может быть проблема?

P.S netstat показывает, что адрес 127.0.0.1:9090 занят питоном, да и проблем с REP-REQ не было

P.P.S заменял pickle на .send_string() и .recv_string(), не помогло,  time.asctime() тоже менял на простую строку

Код сервера:

```
import zmq
import pickle
import sys
import time


def pub_daemon():
    port = "9090"
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        port = sys.argv[1]
        int(port)

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s" % port)

    while True:
        socket.send(pickle.dumps(time.asctime()))
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pub_daemon()
```

Код клиента:

```
import zmq
import pickle
import sys


def sub_daemon():
    port = "9090"
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        port = sys.argv[1]
        int(port)

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s" % port)

    while True:
        data = pickle.loads(socket.recv())
        print(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub_daemon()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали topic для подписки. Для того чтобы задать топик подписки необходимо воспользоваться методом `socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")`, `b""` - означает что вы будете получать абсолютно все данные от сервера.

```
import zmq
import pickle
import sys


def sub_daemon():
    port = "9090"
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        port = sys.argv[1]
        int(port)

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s" % port)

    while True:
        data = pickle.loads(socket.recv())
        print(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub_daemon()
```